# Can I read a file object into a gensim Dictionary class?

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, gensim, corpus

The `gensim` [Dictionary](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html) object keeps track of the vocabulary of the collection of documents (aka corpus). But to feed the data into the object, the data has to be fed into the memory, e.g.

```
import io
from gensim.corpora import Dictionary

infile = '/path/to/data'

with io.open(infile, 'r', encoding='utf8') as fin:
    d = Dictionary(map(lambda x: x.split(), fin.readlines()))
    d.save('data.dict')
```

**Can I read a file object into a gensim Dictionary class?**